# Prove that orthogonal projector operator $P$ onto $L_1$ parallel to $L_2$ is normal iff $L_2=L_1^{\perp}$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, orthogonality

Prove that orthogonal projector operator $P$ onto $L_1$ parallel to $L_2$ is normal iff $L_2=L_1^{\perp}$
**Necessity**:  Let P be an orthogonal projection operator. As $V=L \oplus L^{\perp}$ let $e_1,\ldots,e_k$ be a basis of $L$ and $e_{k+1},\ldots,e_n$ be a basis of $L^{\perp}$
Hence matrix $A_e$ has $k$ ones on diagonal and all other elements are $0$ $\Rightarrow$ $A^*_e=A^T=A_e$ hence $P$ is self-adjoint operator.
**Sufficiency:** Let $P$ be a projection operator onto $L_1$ parallel to $L_2$ ($L_1\oplus L_2=V$) and $P$ is normal operator. Hence $L_2$ = $\ker P$. Let $x\in L_2$, $y \in L_1$ $\Rightarrow$ $(x,y)=(x,A*y_1) = (Ax,y_1) = 0$ hence $L_2 \subset L_1^{\perp}$. So I have to show the same to the other direction, but I don't know how to do that. Could you help? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by $P$ being $\mathit{parallel}$ to $L_2$?

Comment: Sorry for my english. I mean that if $x=x_1+x_2$, where $x_1 \in L_1, x_2 \in L_2$ then $Px=x_1$

Comment: I.e., $\ker P=L_2$.